# Rails 5.2 ActionCable and ActiveStorage when sending images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I try to pass data from client side to server side follow some ActionCable tutorial create image record by ActiveStorage but it does not work.

Here is my code:  Code from client side does pass into server side but I can not create a new image via ActiveStorage. Please help me solve it and give me an idea why it happen. Thanks.

I have tested pass image as base64/blob (I dont really know)

Room_channel.rb

```
def image(check)
post = Post.create title: 'testxcxcx'
post.images.attach check['image'] 
end
```

Room.coffee

```
image: (message) ->
@perform 'image', image: message


$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->


pullfiles = ->
  # love the query selector
    fileInput = document.querySelector('#message-attachment')
    files = fileInput.files

reader = new FileReader()
dataURL = reader.readAsDataURL $('#message-attachment').get(0).files[0]
console.log blod
#App.room.image reader.readAsDataURL  'does not work'
#App.room.image blod                'does not work'
App.room.image document.getElementById('message-attachment').files[0]
console.log document.getElementById('message-attachment').files[0]

reader.addEventListener 'loadend', ->
  console.log 'Here are binary datas !'
  console.log reader.result      
  App.room.image reader.result 'base64 image'

file_name = files[0].name
console.log file_name
file_name2 = $('#message-attachment').get(0).files[0].name
console.log file_name2



 document.querySelector('#message-attachment').onchange = pullfiles
```

Ps: My code above does not take in to account of indentation. It does work in my machine.